# What is the difference between structures containing bool vs uint when using PInvoke?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, structure, union

Ok, I'm now very confused.  [After my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602487) had several people comment about changing bool to uint I verified they are the same size by:

```
    Console.WriteLine("sizeof bool = {0}", Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(bool)));
    Console.WriteLine("sizeof uint = {0}", Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)));
```

Which of course prints:

```
sizeof bool = 4
sizeof uint = 4
```

That said, I then broke down and gave their suggestions a try anyway...  Changing a single bool inside a structure to a uint.  What I can't figure out for the life of me is why this made it work...

So this works:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEY_EVENT_RECORD
{
    public bool bKeyDown;
    public short wRepeatCount;
    public short wVirtualKeyCode;
    public short wVirtualScanCode;
    public char UnicodeChar;
    public int dwControlKeyState;
}
```

When used in this structure:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT_RECORD
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public short EventType;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public KEY_EVENT_RECORD KeyEvent;
}
```

But in this structure it breaks:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct INPUT_RECORD
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public short EventType;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public KEY_EVENT_RECORD KeyEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public MOUSE_EVENT_RECORD MouseEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public WINDOW_BUFFER_SIZE_RECORD WindowBufferSizeEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public MENU_EVENT_RECORD MenuEvent;
    [FieldOffset(4)] public FOCUS_EVENT_RECORD FocusEvent;
}
```

Yet when I change bool bKeyDown to uint in the `KEY_EVENT_RECORD` structure it starts working again...

**Can someone please explain this behavior?**

I really would like to know the why of it so that I can avoid this undocumented feature (aka bug) in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question reworded with a new sample:

[Boolean Marshalling with LayoutKind.Explicit, Is this broken or failing as designed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703759/boolean-marshalling-with-layoutkind-explicit-is-this-broken-or-failing-as-design)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the field type to bool and add the attribute [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)].

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct KEY_EVENT_RECORD
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public bool bKeyDown;
    public short wRepeatCount;
    public short wVirtualKeyCode;
    public short wVirtualScanCode;
    public char UnicodeChar;
    public int dwControlKeyState;
}
```

Docs for [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute.aspx)
Docs for [UnmanagedType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype.aspx)

Comment: I would hope that UnmanagedType.Bool would be the default marshal type for bool... but I've been wrong before.  I tried it anyway and it still fails.  I also tried UnmanagedType.I4 and UnmanagedType.U4 and both of them refuse to allow this decoration on a bool type.

Answer (score 0):

bools are 1byte --> [sizeof (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx)

Also, see [Default Marshaling for Boolean Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx)

Comment: The MarshalAs attribute does not apply to what you're trying to do. For P/Invoke you use the MarshalAs attribute inline.

E.x.:

[DllImport("Kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int nStdHandle);

Comment: Yes I know a bool is represented in C# as a single byte; however, it is always marshalled by default as a 4-byte int.  Thus the question, why does changing bool to uint make a difference?

Comment: I think this is platform dependent. E.x.: It will Marshal.SizeOf will return 4 on a desktop and 1 on a pocket pc.

Look at Rudedog2's post @ http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/f69da088-5be9-4665-878b-3f6efe3b855b